# Multiplying a 2D/3D vector

Tags: opengl, vector

If I have a vector that contains (x,y,z) and a multiply it does it multiply the whole thing?
For example: if my vector is (10, 5, 10) and I multiply it by 10 will the outcome be (100, 50, 100)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Scalars distribute to all components of a vector, no matter the size. A quick Google search would have also revealed this.

Comment: Sorry... I wasn't really sure how to word it... but thanks for the confirmation